# Prokhorov convergence of Gaussian measures

Tags: pr.probability, hilbert-spaces, gaussian

Consider a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and a sequence of centered Gaussian measures $\mu_n$ on it. The covariance operators of $\mu_n$ are defined via their eigenpair(eigenbasis and eigenvalue)) as follows.

Consider real numbers $\alpha_n > 1$ such that $\alpha_n \to \alpha_0$ with $\alpha_0 >1$. The eigenpair for the covariance operator of $\mu_n$ is $\{e_i,i^{-\alpha_n}\}$ where $\{e_i\}$ is some orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$. Does $\mu_n$ converge in Prokhorov metric to a measure $\mu_0$ whose covariance operator has eigenpair $\{e_i,i^{-\alpha_0}\}$?

Comment: I have got the answer. They do indeed converge to the measure. The moderators can close the question.

Comment: I don't see grounds for closing the question; it looks reasonable for this site. If you would like to delete it yourself, you can.